# what does -d value in an if expression in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to understand a part of search function written in a piece of code below is the expression mentioned.

```
if [ -d $1] 
then
<action block>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be `=` after `-d`. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: Yep..got tat... -f works the same for file? is it possible to search from / on using -d/-f options ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You can certainly loop through all the names in a directory and test them each with `-d` and `-f` to report on what they are.

Comment: Please correct the example in the question if it's not copied correctly. As it's written, it won't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it to determine if a directory exist like

```
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
   # code
fi
```

Comment: Yes, but please do not use all-uppercase shell-variable names in order to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Answer (score 2):

The -d is used to find if a given directory is exists or not. If it is exists the condition will be true. if not the condition will be false.

Where as -f is used to find if a given file is exists or not. If it is exists the condition will be true. if not the condition will be false

```
if [ -d "$dirname" ]
then
  echo "directory is present"
else
  echo "directory is not present"
fi
```